# click remove added class after second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to remove `priSCW-active` after second click.

The code needs work but when i click second time on the `container` it is not closing.

What i am missing here anyone can help me in this regard ?

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/dGzPrK?editors=101)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("body").on("click", ".container", function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      var ID = $(this).attr("id");
      $(".priSCWrap").removeClass("priSCW-active");
      $("#open" + ID).toggleClass("priSCW-active").siblings().removeClass('priSCW-active');;
   });
   $("body").click(function(){
         $(".priSCWrap").removeClass("priSCW-active");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you remove the `removeClass()` call, then the toggle will achieve what you need for you. At the moment you remove the class and toggle will then always immediately add it back on again. Also note that the `.priSCWrap` elements are not siblings, so `siblings()` won't select anything. You need to query those elements again and remove the current from the matched set, to remove any existing `priSCWrap-active` classes. Try this:

```
$("body").on("click", ".container", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    var $current = $(this).find('.priSCWrap').toggleClass("priSCW-active");
    $('.priSCWrap').not($current).removeClass('priSCW-active');
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/paw44mzc/1/)

Also note the use of `this` and `find()` which negates the need to bodge together an `id` selector.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: but there is a problem. When i click other .container's then currenct opened div will be stay on there. How to solve this problem ?

Comment: You can use `not()` to exclude the current container, here's a fixed example: https://jsfiddle.net/paw44mzc/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var clicked = 0;
   $("body").on("click", ".container", function(event) {
      if (++clicked === 2) {
          // your code
      }
      event.stopPropagation();
      var ID = $(this).attr("id");
      $(".priSCWrap").removeClass("priSCW-active");
      $("#open" + ID).toggleClass("priSCW-active").siblings().removeClass('priSCW-active');
   });
   $("body").click(function(){
         $(".priSCWrap").removeClass("priSCW-active");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You had to remove this line

```
$(".priSCWrap").removeClass("priSCW-active");
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered to be of low quality. Please explain your solution. The line to be removed is used twice in the code sample.